# AWS SAM CLI ignoring my Python dependencies during build, package, and deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy an AWS Lambda function with the SAM CLI tool, from MacOS, not using Docker containers.

- SAM CLI version 0.4.0
- Python 3.8 runtime for Lambda function
- Python 3.7 installed locally on MacOS
- I have a `requirements.txt` file, in the same directory as my Lambda function file

### Requirements.txt

```
boto3
botostubs
```

### Deploy Script (PowerShell)

```
sam build --template-file $InputTemplate
sam package --region $AWSRegion --template-file $InputTemplate --profile $ProfileName --s3-bucket $BucketName --output-template-file $OutputTemplate
sam deploy --region $AWSRegion --profile $ProfileName --template-file $OutputTemplate --stack-name $StackName --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

### Actual Behavior

SAM CLI is ignoring my `requirements.txt` file, and only deploying my source code. This results in the following error when I test my function.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx': No module named 'botostubs'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

### Expected Behavior

SAM CLI packages up the declared Python dependencies, in `requirements.txt`, along with my source code.

**Question**: How can I ensure that the SAM CLI downloads and packages my Python dependencies, along with my source code? I followed the documentation, to the best of my knowledge.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just figured it out, reading about the `sam build` command in a bit more depth. I didn't realize that it was creating a subfolder called `.aws-sam/build/` and storing the modified template there.

I updated my commands and paths, and it is working just fine now.

```
$InputTemplate = "$PSScriptRoot/cloudformation.yml"
$BuiltTemplate = "$PSScriptRoot/.aws-sam/build/template.yaml"
$BucketName = 'xxxxxxx'
$AWSRegion = 'xxxxxx'
$StackName = 'xxxxxx'

# Package and deploy the application
sam build --template-file $InputTemplate
sam package --region $AWSRegion --template-file $BuiltTemplate --profile $ProfileName --s3-bucket $BucketName
sam deploy --region $AWSRegion --profile $ProfileName --template-file $BuiltTemplate --stack-name $StackName --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --s3-bucket $BucketName
```

Comment: Stop sending --template-file to sam package and sam deploy. It will automatically use the one in the build directory.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar problem and root cause of my failure was that I was specifying --template-file template.yml. As per this issue https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1252 SAM CLI looks for the code uri specified in my template.yml and uploads only the function code.

So my solution was:

1. specify *--template-file* in *sam build*
2. run *sam deploy* without *--template-file* option

Comment: This solution worked for me! It applies to the `sam package` command as well i.e. do NOT mention the template file option when running `sam package` after `sam deploy`.

Comment: The reason this works is because the `sam deploy` command automagically picks up the compiled `template.yaml` in  the `.aws-sam` directory, which is created by running `sam build`. If you inspect this generated `template.yaml` you'll see that the lambda references a directory within `.aws-sam` that contains the code and all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem. Resolved it by changing directory into the build folder (doesn't use these directory shell variables)

```
sam build --use-container
cd .aws-sam/build/
sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket sdd-s3-basebucket --output-template-file packaged.yaml
sam deploy --template-file ./packaged.yaml --stack-name prod --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region eu-central-1
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your 'requirements.txt' file is right under the path specified in 'CodeUri' attribute of the Lambda in your template file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mmy solution was:
specify --template-file in sam build
run sam deploy without --template-file option
```

It works but everytime starts script, it ask about confirmation about deploying changset - it is not a problem when I use script but problem appears when it is executed by CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

I use poetry for the dependencies, and use it to create a requirements.txt

`poetry export -f requirements.txt --output ./app/requirements.txt --without-hashes`

I had used diffent python versions in pyproject.toml (poetry) and template.yaml (sam). So sam would not install any of the requirements:

`fastapi==0.109.2 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "3.12"`
because they were not compatible with the pyhton3.10 specified in the yaml.

Maybe someone will have the same bug one day...